# How to deduce the current function from the graph?

Tags: current, circuit-analysis, power-electronics

I want to express the current function based on the next graph

[image]

So using the slope and the coordinates in the third interval the current will be
\$i(t)=\begin{cases}
0\,A & 0\,s<t<t_{1}\,s\\
7\,A & t_{1}\\
y-7=\frac{8-7}{t_{2}-t{1}}(x-t_{1}) A& t_{1}<t<t_{2}\\
8\,A & t_{2}\\
\\
\end{cases}\$

This is the right approach?
I intend to use the expression to calculate the average and rms current.
Also if can point me more problems like this.

Comment: https://masteringelectronicsdesign.com/how-to-derive-the-rms-value-of-pulse-and-square-waveforms/

Comment: Yes, it's the right approach.

Comment: What's ‘x’, what’s ‘t2’, what’s ‘y’? Also, what happens at t>t2?